# Api-Platform GET itemOperation to get User by E-Mail or Username

Tags: api-platform.com

How can I use a custom controller action to get an entity by its second identifier like get User by Email oder Username?

I tried to write the resource.yaml like this:

```
App\Entity\User:
    itemOperations:
        get:
            method: 'GET'
            path: '/users/{id}'
        getByEmail:
            method: 'GET'
            path: '/users/email/{emailaddress}'
            controller: 'App\Controller\User\GetByEmailAction'
```

Is this a possible approach at all or is it only the way to call GET on the collection and use a filter like `/users?email=...`?

Comment: If you want the parameters from the path to be passed to your Controller directly you need to configure the operation with "read"=false. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589694/how-to-write-custom-endpoints-with-parameters-not-related-to-any-specific-entity)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a custom operation.

```
namespace App\Controllers;
class GetByEmailAction {
  public function __invoke($emailaddress, EntityManagerInterface $em) {
     $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy[
         'email' => $emailaddress
     ];
     if (!$user) {
         throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
     }
     return $user;
  }
}
```

check the docs for more examples [Custom operation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers)